# I'm one of three/four men at my office, but typically I'm the only one wearing a tie. Am I overdressing?

Tags: dress-code

I work as an IT assistant for a medical supplies sales company, that's part of a small web of companies which includes different kinds of medical facilities. Our office is fairly female dominated, with the only males being myself, the IT manager, an apprentice in the accounts department and occasionally the boss, who is often away on business or is himself at one of the clinics treating patients.

The dress code here is office attire, which of course is a fairly broad and liberal rule for women. However, for men that typically means a dress shirt, some smart trousers or chinos and *maybe* a tie. Unless the boss is in and has been/is going to a meeting of some description, I am typically the only one here who wears a tie with my dress shirt. My manager did mention when I started here that I didn't have to wear a tie if I didn't want to, but as I quite like wearing one (shocking, I know) I have continued to do so. No further questioning or grievance has come about from my dress code, and I have even had colleagues compliment my choice of tie on a few occasions. However, I do wonder if I come across as stuffy or try-hard by being the sole tie-wearer in the workplace. Should that be a genuine concern?

Comment: If this "issue" has genuinely made it anywhere near the top of your list of things to be concerned about you either have a very unstressful job or or some seriously out of what priorities! :) Seriously though you don't need to worry, no one has told you it's bad and you've even had positive feedback from colleages. You're fine.

Comment: Not a concern. Personally, I think ties are sexist medieval torture devices, but if you like to wear them, then wearing one just states that you like to wear them. Some women, when given the option of wearing flats wear insanely high heels, because they like the look.  Wearing a tie says nothing more or less as a choice than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> No further questioning or grievance has come about from my dress code, and I have even had colleagues compliment my choice of tie on a few occasions.

There's your answer. If anything, your coworkers probably think you're a snazzy dresser! Since you've never been questioned or teased about it there's nothing to worry about. If a tie makes you comfortable and confident, that will come across to others. Your coworkers understand "oh, that's just how McOwen dresses" and likely don't give it a second thought.

If they do ever poke fun at you for it, just remind them of the old adage "dress for the job you want" :)

Answer (score 13):

You are over thinking this. If you want to wear a tie - wear one. If you do not need to wear a tie and you do not want to wear a tie - don't

Comment: Overthinking about overdressing. :)

Comment: If everyone else, including the bosses, were wearing shorts and flip-flops, I would probably argue that a tie is overdressing. If everyone else is dressing business professional, wearing a tie is incredibly reasonable.